# is it possible to assign a domain to a "folder" created dynamically?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, directory

I'm developing a service where I need to have different domains for pages created dynamically, for instance, I will have something like this:

example.net/?client=hello

I think, with htaccess I can achieve this:

example.net/hello

Is it possible to point a domain to that "folder" ?

Comment: No, you can't. The document root for each domain(in this case "hello" folder) must exist on the server not aliased via htaccess.

Comment: :/ ok, thanks for the answer, i think i will create the folder with PHP, thanks a lot for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by `point a domain to that folder`. But if you would like to rewrite `example.net/hello` to `example.net/index.php?client=hello` you could do like this:

```
# check so it's not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# check so it's not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=d
# do we have a client name in the url?
# valid names are not case sensitive and containing letters between a-z
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([a-zA-Z]+)$
# pass the client name to index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?client=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The other way around, if you would like to rewrite `index.php?client=hello` to a existing folder named `hello` this should work:

```
# check so it's not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=d
# check so we have a valid query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^client=([a-zA-Z]+)$
# check so the client directory really exists
RewriteCond %1 -d
# rewrite to client folder and strip of the query string 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1? [L]
```